# Ionic Build vs Serve differences

Tags: android, mobile, ionic-framework

I don't know why? but the serve --lab and build has different output...

[This is what it looks like on my android device (Lenovo A536)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVooi.png)
[And this is what it looks like on my --lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e0oY.png)

Also in the lab app made for ionic... The add new item is not working... I wonder why? I started from the blank template.

Comment: did you try to add platform for both android and ios?

Comment: once you are done with the changes, you have to run ionic build android/ios command, to update the apk/.ipa file.

Comment: yes... they were done in the very first steps...

Comment: every time when you make changes in ur www folder, you have to run "ionic build android" to reflect changes for ur android apk

Comment: These are also done...

Comment: Also... when I have a firebase as dependency... but the time i remove firebase from angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'firebase']) it runs ok...